# postgres data directory empty but table exits

Tags: postgresql

I'm confused on where to find locations of a database in PostgreSQL.

I know the command `SHOW data_directory`. Specifically, I set up a cluster in the location `data/postgres`. When I connect to this cluster and create database in it, `SHOW data_directory` returns the following result:

```
yql@ubuntu1804:/data/postgresdb$ sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433
Password: 
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c sample
You are now connected to database "sample" as user "postgres".
sample=# show data_directory;
 data_directory 
----------------
 /postgresdb
(1 row)
```

Using `\dt` lists the following results, so the database should not be empty:

```
                 List of relations
 Schema |           Name           | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------------------------+-------+----------
 citydb | address                  | table | postgres
 citydb | address_to_bridge        | table | postgres
 citydb | address_to_building      | table | postgres
 citydb | ade                      | table | postgres
 citydb | aggregation_info         | table | postgres
 citydb | appear_to_surface_data   | table | postgres
 citydb | appearance               | table | postgres
 citydb | breakline_relief         | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge                   | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_constr_element    | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_furniture         | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_installation      | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_open_to_them_srf  | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_opening           | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_room              | table | postgres
 citydb | bridge_thematic_surface  | table | postgres
 citydb | building                 | table | postgres
 citydb | building_furniture       | table | postgres
 citydb | building_installation    | table | postgres
 citydb | city_furniture           | table | postgres
 citydb | citymodel                | table | postgres
 citydb | cityobject               | table | postgres
 citydb | cityobject_genericattrib | table | postgres
 citydb | cityobject_member        | table | postgres
 citydb | cityobjectgroup          | table | postgres
 citydb | database_srs             | table | postgres
 citydb | external_reference       | table | postgres
 citydb | generalization           | table | postgres
 citydb | generic_cityobject       | table | postgres
 citydb | grid_coverage            | table | postgres
 citydb | group_to_cityobject      | table | postgres
 citydb | implicit_geometry        | table | postgres
 citydb | index_table              | table | postgres
 citydb | land_use                 | table | postgres
 citydb | masspoint_relief         | table | postgres
 citydb | objectclass              | table | postgres
 citydb | opening                  | table | postgres
```

However, the directory `/data/postgresdb` is empty. How could this be the case? If so, where are all these tables stored?

Thanks!

Comment: `/data/postgresdb` <> `/postgresdb`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The data is in `postgresdb`. I indeed did not specify the full path (only relative path) when creating this cluster. Thanks!